# printing $variable from mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, variables, eof

I have a mysql binary table that I am storing html email layout. In this layout I want to put tags that are populated in the page that the layout will be called in. I can't seem to get it to display anything but the tags.

Example:

called from mysql database ->

```
 $sql_result = 'The property name is $prop_name.';

 $message = <<<EOF
 $sql_result
 EOF;
```

When I load the page it will email the result with `$prop_name` instead of the actual name that is defined earlier in the scripting. The display on the page its works for the pre-defined `$prop_name` variable but the emailed part does not display it. Even when I echo or print the result on the same page it will just put the `$prop_name` instead of the earlier defined call.  How do I get the variable to show the pre-defined defintion for it when I call it from a database?

Comment: I guess to some it up I am trying to build a email template that a user can edit. By inserting some pre-defined variables or tags it will email things like the property name that was seen on the screen at the same time the page was displayed.

Comment: If you change the single quotes to double quotes, `$prop_name` will be properly substituted, as long as it has a value.

Answer (score 1):

If you pull "The property name is $prop_name." out of the database, that is just pure text. It will not change the $prop_name with your $prop_name variable.

What you should do is simply replace the text.

Thus:

```
$prop_name = "Finca el Otero";
$output = str_replace('$prop_name', $prop_name, $sql_result);
echo $output;
```

This will replace the $prop_name anchor in your text (as in your $sql_result variable) with the content of your $prop_name variable.

Comment: Thanks a million! I figured it had to do with it just being text but couldn't come up with how to fix it.. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to flag my answer as correct (tick the V at the left of my answer).